# Вывод чисел при суммирование в массиве

Tags: php

Данный цикл выводит сумму чисел в массиве. Ума не приложу, что нужно дописать, чтобы цикл помимо суммы выводил и числа которые суммирует.

Например:

0 + 1 = 1

1 + 2 = 3

3 + 3 = 6 и т.д.

```js
$massive = [1,2,3,4,5];


function opa(...$numbers){                    

$result = 0;

foreach($numbers as $items){                                
                                              
echo "   =".$result = $result + $items;

}}


opa(...$massive);
```

Comment: `foreach($numbers as $item){ $result += $item; echo "item=$item\n"; } echo "result=$result\n"; `

Comment: числа не вышли, вот что получилось: item=1 item=2 item=3 item=4 item=5 result=15 у меня php8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
$result = 0;

foreach($numbers as $items){  
    echo $result . "+" . $items . " = " . ($result += $items) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: а почему без скобок ($result += $items) будет ошибка? в чем проблема?

Comment: У ошибки есть текст. Что там написано?

Comment: Это значит что при отсутствии скобок php пытается прибавить к `$result` значение `$items . "\n"`, которое не является числом.

Comment: а что дают скобки? что они делают?

Comment: Повышают приоритет операции.

Comment: а скобки называются просто скобками или у них есть научное название?

Comment: Скобки это просто скобки.